# Multipule VBO in Opengl

Tags: opengl, sprites, vbo

I have currently in my application 2 VBO one which is a streamed buffer and for the moment the other is a static buffer.

However even when the steam buffer is not bound and the static buffer is bound calling drawarray will use the data from the streamed buffer rather than the static one.

The streamed buffer is used for sprite batching and is created as followed

```
VBO = new VertexBuffer();
VBO->createBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferSize, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
//void VertexBuffer::createBuffer(GLenum Type, GLsizei size, GLenum usage)
// {
//  glGenBuffers(1, &m_BufferID);
//  m_size = size;
//  m_Type = Type;
//  bind();
//  glBufferData(m_Type, m_size, NULL,  usage);
//  unbind();
// }

VBO->bind();
//void bind()       {glBindBuffer(m_Type, m_BufferID);}

VBO->setBufferData(NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
//void VertexBuffer::setBufferData(GLvoid* Data, GLenum usage)
// {
//  glBufferData(m_Type, m_size, Data, usage);
// }

//enable the vertex attributes for the VAO in this case vertex pos and texture are needed
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXPOS);  // Vertex position
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)MLRenderer::ML_ATT_TEXTURE0); //vertex texture coord
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXCOL);

glVertexAttribPointer(MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXPOS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol), (GLubyte *)NULL );
glVertexAttribPointer(MLRenderer::ML_ATT_TEXTURE0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol), (GLubyte*)sizeof(Vector3f));
glVertexAttribPointer(MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXCOL, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol), (GLubyte*)(sizeof(Vector2f) + sizeof(Vector3f)));

VBO->unbind();
//void unbind() {glBindBuffer(m_Type, 0);}
```

Rendering using that buffer is as followed

```
VBO->bind();
//lock the shader
m_shader->lock();
//apply the uniforms

m_shader->addUniform("inMVP", (MLRenderer::MLCoreGL::getOrtho()));
m_shader->addUniform("Tex1", 0);

//*INFO*
//In order for the mapping to work correctly a max limit needs to be made for the vbo
//this will then be filled with data up to a point. once the data is filled then a new
//mapped range is needed and the draw call can be made. this means only a max amount of sprites
//can be batch drawn but it meas a fixed size index buffer is possible
if (m_BufferOffset +  (count * m_spriteSize) >= m_BufferSize)
{
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferSize, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    VBO->setBufferData(m_BufferSize, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    m_BufferOffset = 0;
}

MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol* mappedData = (MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol*)VBO->mapRange(m_BufferOffset, m_BufferOffset +  (count  * m_spriteSize));

//!!!---set vertex Data----!!!

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
VBO->unmap();


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, (m_BufferOffset/sizeof(MLFormats::VertexPosTexCol)), count * 6);
m_BufferOffset += (count * m_spriteSize);


VBO->unbind();
//unbind the texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//unlock the shader 
m_shader->unlock();
```

That all works no problem but its when it comes to my point sprite rendering that I get a problem.

The static buffer is created like so

```
//create a new buffer with the right size;
m_PointBuffer = new VertexBuffer();
m_PointBuffer->createBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vector3f) * 2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
m_PointBuffer->bind();

//set the vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXPOS);
glVertexAttribPointer(MLRenderer::ML_ATT_VERTEXPOS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3f), (GLubyte*)NULL);


//DEMO ADD A TEMP POINT
Vector3f v3[2];
v3[0] = Vector3f(400,400, 0);
v3[1] = Vector3f(300,660, 0);
m_PointBuffer->setBufferData(sizeof(Vector3f) * 2, (GLvoid*)v3, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//void VertexBuffer::setBufferData(GLsizei size, GLvoid* Data, GLenum usage)
// {
//  glBufferData(m_Type, size, Data, usage);
// }
m_PointBuffer->unbind();
```

Then when I come to draw the point sprites

```
m_PointBuffer->bind();
m_pointSpriteShader->lock();

m_pointSpriteShader->addUniform("inMV", m_modelView);
m_pointSpriteShader->addUniform("Tex1", 0);
m_pointSpriteShader->addUniform("Size2", m_halfSize);
m_pointSpriteShader->addUniform("ProjectionMat", MLRenderer::MLCoreGL::getOrtho());

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);

m_PointBuffer->unbind();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

m_pointSpriteShader->unlock();
```

Im sure there is something im missing completely but at the moment I cant see what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dekowta

In your case I would rewrite the draw code next way:

1. Apply shader
2. Setup uniforms
3. Bind needed buffer (**glBindBuffer**)
4. Setup attrib pointers (**glVertexAttribPointer**)
5. Do not forget to enable them (**glEnableVertexAttribArray**)
6. call **glDrawArrays**
7. disable attribs (**glDisableVertexAttribArray**)

OpenGL is a state machine and the fact that you setup vertex attribs between bind/unbind of **VBO** does not really mean that when you bind your **VBO** next time all vertex attribs will be enabled again.

Nice documentation about using Vertex Buffer Objects can be found [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html)

Answer (score 4):

As has been stated [many](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46184/opengl-is-it-possible-to-use-vaos-without-specifying-a-vbo/46605#46605), [*many*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) times before, `glVertexAttribPointer` takes the buffer object that was bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` ***at the time the function is called***. Changing the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding will have no effect on rendering unless you make the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls again.